# Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

It gives an error when I run this code, help me to resolve this error.
Incorrect syntax near '='.

my question about what kind error is this.?

```
namespace SqlCommandBuilders
{
    public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            string sqlQuery = "Select * from tblStudents where ID = "+txtStudentID.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Students");

            ViewState["SQL_QUERY"] = sqlQuery;
            ViewState["DATASET"] = ds;

            if(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[0];
                txtStudentID.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                txtTotalMarks.Text = dr["TotalMarks"].ToString();
                ddlGender.SelectedValue = dr["Gender"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblStatus.Text = "No Student Record with ID =" + txtStudentID.Text;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us in which line the error occurs. Please post the complete error/exception details.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the string you're creating for a moment. Suppose `txtStudentID.Text` is the string `Joe`. You'd be creating `Select * from tblStudents where ID = Joe` which is obviously incorrect. `Joe` needs quotes around it.

***But***, don't just put quotes around it. [Here's why](http://bobby-tables.com/):

[image]

The correct thing to do is use a parameterized statement, as described on [here](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) the site linked above. Applying their example to your code, we'd get something like:

```
SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblStudents where ID = @username",  con);
sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtStudentID.Text);
```

...but I don't know what your `ViewState` thing is, so can't help you apply it there.

Answer (score 1):

SQL commands that use text input by users should almost ALWAYS use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks and syntax errors, and it's also good to get in the habit of wrapping disposable objects (like database connections) in `using` statements:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    string sqlQuery = "Select * from tblStudents where ID = @studentId";
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con)) {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@studentId", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                                   .Value = txtStudentID.Text;
        da.Fill(ds, "Students");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here.

SQL parameters should always be used in cases such as this.

Also, Is Student ID a text field in the database or a number?

If its a numeric, where is the textbox being initialized?  The page_load is one of the first things that happen, and since you are running this on all page_loads (even the first time), if its an empty string, it'll definitely crash regardless of whether you use parameters or not, because an empty string cannot be converted to a number.